# Possible usage for Vala under non-linux environments?

Tags: gtk, glib, vala, gobject

Assuming that I'm willing to invest in Vala, I noticed that using under a typical GNU/linux distribution is relatively easy and productive especially when creating GUIs, the question is: what I can do with this language and GTK-stuff under other platforms ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't really any cross-platform issues inherent to Vala, so what you really need to concern yourself with is GLib and GTK+ (if you want to using).

GTK+ (and GLib/GObject/GIO) do support Windows; there are [32-bit](http://www.gtk.org/download/win64.php) and [64-bit](http://www.gtk.org/download/win64.php) packages available.  There is also support for [OS X](http://www.gtk.org/download/macos.php).  Windows and OS X support historically haven't been as solid as Linux but there are applications like Inkscape, GIMP, and Wireshark, which have GTK+ UIs and work on Windows and OS X.

Comment: ok but there are a bozillion of different platforms and architectures out there, for example what about Android and iOS ? What About a GNU/Linux distribution that runs on ARM ? It's always the same ?, As I understand this Vala depends on Glib and Gobject, not on GTK stuff, but how portable is Glib and Gobject ? There are any restrictions in terms of features ? For example I can perform multithreading on the X platform ? This will work on a big endian ?

Comment: People have managed to get GLib and Vala working on both Android (easy) and iOS (harder).  GIO is a bit harder to port, and I'm not really sure what the status on Android and iOS are, but Vala only requires it for async methods and D-Bus.  That said, it's kind of pointless--none of the iOS or Android libraries have Vala bindings, so if you actually want to do something *useful* it's going to be a lot of work.  Exotic architectures aren't really a problem--ARM works great, big endian (or even PDP-endian) isn't a problem.  The difficulty is dealing with weird *platforms*, not architectures.